# how to traverse in a unordered_map of unordered_map of unordered_map in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I wanted to traverse inside a data structure - unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>>> myMap. To further specify I want to get the data elements like ->
myMap[someVal1][someVal2]
{all second elements of this unordered map}

I am aware of the fact that the same could by done by a 3d array however using a 3d array would not be efficient as the data range is huge and the program would end up using far more space than required.I tried using some iterators like unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>>>::iterator i, and several other such iterators however it always ends up in some error or the other. Could someone help me in understanding how this map can be traversed ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could traverse the map with a foreach loop (it needs C++11, I think that won't be a problem), if you don't want to use iterators.

```
myMap mapMapMap;
for(auto& mapMap : mapMapMap){
    for(auto& map : mapMap.second){
        for(auto& key_value : map.second){
            int key = key_value.first;
            int value = key_value.second;
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you didn't want to iterate all the map, but only the values of the third level, given the two first, then this should make it:

```
int k1, k2;
for(auto& key_value : myMap.at(k1).at(k2)){
    //...
}
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not sureif it works (so I don't include this in the answer) but maybe you can use `std::unordered_map<int[3], int>` but I'm not sure it compiles.

Comment: well the code you mentioned in the answer could work however I don't wanna use 3 loops. let's say I wanna use a single loop because some values are known - (val1 and val2). and I just want to access the elements within mymap[val1][val2]. this could be done in a single loop so clearly using multiloops would just increase the complexity

Comment: @PranavMehta then you could just do 
`for(auto& key_value : myMap.get(val1).get(val2)){
    //...
}
`. I'll edit my answer to add that